# 'my homeland even if it was unjust to me is still to me dear'

Tags: phrases, popular-refrains

> My homeland, even if it is unjust to me is still dear.

An Arabic poet said this line when many told him to betray the government that wronged and oppressed him, and show the enemy the way to enter the country, thus becoming something like a fifth columnist.

He refused because he would rather be wronged by his own fellow citizen than by a foreigner and always be seen as a traitor. Regardless of all the injustice and hardship he has gone through he chose not to betray his country. He is against the government and system but not against his country.

He died on the battlefield and he said those lines and the ruler at that time shed tears when he knew about he said.

Is there a similar line in English literature?

Comment: It doesn't matter for your question, but did you mean to make the quoted text different in the title and the body?

Comment: Socrates expressed this idea when he was sentenced to death, but I'm not aware of any pithy rendering or quote which captures his sentiment in English.

Comment: Kipling wrote a poem titled 'England, Right or Wrong'.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unfamiliar with a literary quote or expression about patriotism in spite of personal persecution or prosecution; however, *our country, right or wrong* is sometimes used as a patriotic cry in the U.S., and is properly understood as an acknowledgment that one's country is sometimes in the wrong.

An early version is [attributed to](http://hamptonroadsnavalmuseum.blogspot.com/2012/04/my-country-right-or-wrong-what-decatur.html) a toast by Commodore [Stephen Decatur, Jr.](http://www.biography.com/people/stephen-decatur-9269384), in April 1816, when he had returned home after success in the [Barbary Wars](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1801-1829/barbary-wars). Alexander Mackenzie's *Life of Stephen Decatur* (1848) gives it as

> Our country! In her intercourse with foreign nations, may she always be in the right; but our country, right or wrong.

It is a wish that one's country (the United States in his case) should always strive to be in the right, not that she should be considered always to be in the right, but that one should acknowledge one's country even in the wrong.

U.S Senator Carl Schurz (R-Wisconsin) is credited with popularizing a more explicitly cautionary version of the quote:

> My country, right or wrong; if right, to be kept right; and if wrong, to be set right.

That is, one's patriotism is dependent upon righteousness, not simply nationalistic loyalty, and it is the duty of a patriot to keep one's country on the righteous path.

(The U.S. government had been selling munitions left over from the U.S. Civil War to private firms, but it emerged that some of those arms had made their way into the hands of French agents during the [Franco-Prussian War](https://www.britannica.com/event/Franco-German-War). German-Americans, Schurz among them, criticized the sales as a breach of American neutrality. Their opponents in turn accused them of being unpatriotic for attacking the administration, and it is to that accusation that Schurz is recorded [making the quote](http://www.bartleby.com/73/1641.html) on February 29, 1872.)

Just saying *our country, right or wrong* does suggest a sort of blind or jingoistic patriotism, however— and it is often abused as such in political discourse. I would recommend using Schurz's longer version if you do use this phrase.